# Android studio 2 issue after update to preview 6

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated to android studio 2.0 to preview 6.

I got this error message:

[image: Error]

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, 
     or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "aed79d567e57792ed352e708d2b7ca891ff897c6"
```

When i click on the options `Fix plugin version and sync project`

Project get synced but nothing happens.

When i click on Open File, it opens `build.gradle` file which associated to App module. it puts the cursor on this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Any clue what is the ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable ?
or what can be this error ?

Comment: click check for update and re-update your AS

Comment: i had the issue with preview 5, could you restart your AS ? and see besides the title if it mention preview 5 or 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you try changing the class path of your build.gradle to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
}
}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: it looks like gonna work, it needs to update the gradle wrapper to 2.10 as well, it is updating now.

Comment: I hope it works.Faced the same error three days ago.